# Ionic 2: Separate navigation stack for tabs - show back arrow & menu toggle depending on selected tab

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm developing an Ionic mobile App (current version). I have a tabs-structure looking similar to this:

[image: example tabs structure]

In each tab I'm starting a new navigation stack. Meaning: Clicking ob the "push page" button for example pushes the new page to the first page's navigation stack.

In the upper left corner I have the menu-symbol to open my side menu. Whenever I push a page to the root-navigation-stack, this symbol changes to become the "back-arrow".

What I want is, that this symbol always represents the navigation stack of the selected tab. So when I push a page to the first page's navigation stack I want to show the back-arrow. When I then change to the second page, I want the menu-symbol to be shown, until I push a page to the second page's navigation stack. And so on...

Does anybody have an idea how to achieve this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ionic2, you can customize the menu icon according to your needs. For every page that you need to customize the icon, add ion-header tag to its. For eg.

**FirstPage.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar hideBackButton="true">
    <button ion-button menuToggle (click)="backToMain()">
      <ion-icon name="back"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>First Page</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
</ion-content>
```

**SecondPage.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar hideBackButton="true">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>First Page</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Using Tabs, the html file where the header comes from is always the same one. E.g. "home.html". "firstPage.html" and "seconPage.html" are loaded by home.html and shown behind the header of home.html. Hence, this approach unfortunately wouldn't work.